# Oracle Service Bus vs Oracle Fusion Middleware

Tags: oracle, soa, esb, oracle-fusion-middleware

I came to know that aqualogic service bus is renamed to oracle service bus when oracle acquired BEA. Is there a relationship between oracle fusion middleware and oracle service bus or are they totally independent of each other? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle Service Bus is a product within the Oracle Fusion Middleware suite.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Integration aims to connect and combine people, processes, systems, and technologies to ensure that the right people and the right processes have the right information ant the right resources at the right time.

Integration can be done using

1. Integration Framework
2. ESB
3. Integration Suite

The Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) has been most widely accepted as a tool to support application integration. However it is to be noted that on the integration complexity path, an ESB usually falls between a framework and a suite as an alternative for application integration.

OSB is an Enterprise Service Bus and Oracle Fusion middleware is an Integration Suite.